# How to display system.out (in console) on ant?

Tags: java, ant, build, classpath, system.out

I am able to build java program on ant and it has been configured properly. However i'm wondering how would i see System.out.println / System.out.print on console using Ant ?

**Note:** i haven't used ant and i am trying to explore. I hope my question is not stupid ?

Simple program

```
    package antTesting;
    public class Helloworld
    {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            System.out.println( " hello there !!!! " );

        }

    }
```

build.xml for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />

  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    </javac>

  </target>

  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\de.vogella.build.test.ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

when i `run > ant`

on CMD

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\Sprinter\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\Sprinter\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Buildfile: C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\build
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\docs
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\dist

makedir:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\docs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\dist

compile:
    [javac] C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\build.xml:26: warning: 'inc
ludeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false
 for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\
build

jar:
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\dist\de.vogel
la.build.test.ant.jar

docs:
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] Loading source file C:\Users\ms025226\workspace\TestingWorld\src\Hel
loworld.java...
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_31
  [javadoc] Building tree for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] Building index for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
  [javadoc] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\
HP\Sprinter\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\Sprinter\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\ja
smine.jar
  [javadoc] Building index for all classes...

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

When i defined **target for classpath** i am receiving an error

```
<!-- to printoutputs -->    
  <target name="Helloworld" description="Hello world">
        <java classname="antTesting.Helloworld">
            <arg value="arg1"/>
            <arg value="arg2"/>         
        </java>
 </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs, Helloworld">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>
```

**ERROR:**

```
Helloworld:
     [java] Could not find antTesting.Helloworld. Make sure you have it in your classpath
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:138)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:764)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:218)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
     [java] Java Result: -1
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Doesn't look like your ant script executes your program or anything. Just compiles and builds some code and javadoc. Is the "main" target executing your program? Post your ant script.

Comment: I dont think I follow.  Do you mean Java's sysout like from a JUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute your class from Ant, you are not specifying it anywhere, add somehting like this to your script:

```
<target name="Helloworld" description="Hello world">
    <java classname="your.package.Helloworld">
        <arg value="arg1"/>
        <arg value="arg2"/>
        ...
    </java>
</target>
```

The elements `<arg value="..."/>` are passed to your **main** method array parameter: `main( String[] args )`

Now add the target `Helloworld` as a dependency to other target or select it from the run options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need System.out or would using the logging (Apache Commons, SLF4J...) be more interesting?